# Using Exception Handling in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, exception, while-loop

Using exception handling inside a loop in python, I'm receiving inputs from a user and adds it to a list but if the user types 'done' the loop terminates and sums up the list. If the user types any other non numeric data it would print 'Wrong Data' and continue the loop. My issues are: Adding the list. Converting the user data from number to string. Reading a string data first from the user. And terminating the loop with 'done'.

```
total = 0
user_list = []


while True:
    try:
        user_entry = int(input('(\'done\' is your terminator.)\nEnter any number only! >>  '))
        user_list.append(user_entry)
        total = total + user_list
    except ValueError:
        if str(user_entry) == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong Data')
            continue
```

Comment: To be able to terminate, you should read in 2 steps, first `user_entry = input(...)` then try to convert `user_entry = int(user_entry)` . Otherwise, `user_entry = int(input(...))` will error when you write 'done', and the 'done' will never be assigned to the variable, and the condition in the except block will never be True.

Comment: PS: Please do not make your whole text as a title using `#`, it is too big and not readable.

Comment: about the total: try to check what the code `total = total + user_list` is doing. You are trying to add a number (0 at the beginning) with a list. I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: I'd suggest you to add some debugging code to help you see what happens in each step of the loop. Something like `print(total)` and `print(user_list)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of code in the `try` block that should go before or after the `try` statement.

```
total = 0
user_list = []

while True:
    user_entry = input('(\'done\' is your terminator.)\nEnter any number only! >>  ')

    if user_entry == 'done':
        break

    try:
        user_entry = int(user_entry)
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong Data')
        continue

    user_list.append(user_entry)
    total += user_entry
```

Note that instead of keeping running total, you can simply wait until after the loop to call `total = sum(user_list)`.